# Storing the scraped data in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy

I want to store the scraped data in MongoDb, but I am getting an error.

File "C:\Pythom27\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 599 , in iteritems
return d.iteritems(**kw)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritem'. 
I have not used attribute has iteritem anywhere in the program
Here is the program code:
 ex.py

```
import scrapy
from example.items import ExampleItem


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'aaa'
    allowed_domains = ["in.bookmyshow.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://in.bookmyshow.com/movies"]

  def parse(self, response):
    links = response.xpath('//a/@href').re('movies/[^\/]+\/.*$')
    for url in set(links):
        url = response.urljoin(url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_movie)

  def parse_movie(self, response):
    item = {}
    item['Moviename'] = map(unicode.strip, response.xpath('.//h1[@id="eventTitle"]/text()').extract())
    item['Language'] = map(unicode.strip, response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/span[1]/a/text()').extract())
    item['Info'] = map(unicode.strip, response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/span[3]/a/text()').extract())
    yield item
```

settings.py:

```
 BOT_NAME = 'example'

 SPIDER_MODULES = ['example.spiders']
 NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'example.spiders'

 ITEM_PIPELINES = ['example.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline', ]

 MONGODB_SERVER = "localhost"
 MONGODB_PORT = 27017
 MONGODB_DB = "ticketbook"
 MONGODB_COLLECTION = "movies"
```

pipleline.py

```
import pymongo

from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy import log

class ExamplePipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
    connection = pymongo.Connection(settings['MONGODB_HOST'], settings['MONGODB_PORT'])
    db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DATABASE']]
    self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.collection.insert(dict(item))
    log.msg("Item wrote to MongoDB database {}, collection {}, at host {}, port {}".format(
        settings['MONGODB_DATABASE'],
        settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION'],
        settings['MONGODB_HOST'],
        settings['MONGODB_PORT']))
    return item
```

I would like to know where i have gone wrong..

Comment: Please provide full traceback.

Comment: (Note that you don't need the `valid` boolean: raising `DropItem` exception will stop the execution anyway.)

Comment: How do you call `process_item`?

Comment: process_item is a default method which gets called as soon as it enters pipelines.py

Comment: The items that are being yield/scraped, one of the items needs to be a dictionary but instead you are passing a list, hence the error. I am assuming something within parse_movie. print the items and check.

I think the problem is when you are using `map`.
What does `unicode.strip` do?

Also, use xpath such as `'//span[@class="__language"]/a/text()` to extract data. Make use of class names, id's. Keep Xpath's as small as possible.

Comment: parse_movie is working fine. I am able to scrape the data but when i make changes in settings,py and pipeline.py to store it into MongoDB there is error. unicode.strip is to remove tab and nextline character(\t ,\n) @Vaulstien

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py, change the ITEMS_PIPELINES from a list to a dictionary like so:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = { 'example.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline': 100 }
```

See explanation: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#activating-an-item-pipeline-component